# How to display the light box on click of each image?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to display lightbox on click of each image. I want to keep same class and name for each image. The idea is to make the page dynamic which is why I have kept the same id and class on on image tag.

When I click on the first image the lightbox is getting open but when I keep the same id and class for the second and third image the lightbox is not getting open. I want to display the lightbox on click of each image.

```
<head>
<style>

    /* The Modal (background) */
    .modal {
        display: none; /* Hidden by default */
        position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
        z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
        padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%; /* Full width */
        height: 100%; /* Full height */
        overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
        background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
    }

    /* Modal Content */
    .modal-content {
        background-color: #fefefe;
        margin: auto;
        padding: 20px;
        border: 1px solid #888;
        width: 80%;
    }

    /* The Close Button */
    .close {
        color: #aaaaaa;
        float: right;
        font-size: 28px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    .close:hover,
    .close:focus {
        color: #000;
        text-decoration: none;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    </style>

</head>



<body>




<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<a href="#" id="myBtn"><img src="http://theparlour21.se/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/granat-salad.png"></a>
<a href="#" id="myBtn"><img src="http://theparlour21.se/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/granat-salad.png"></a>
<a href="#" id="myBtn"><img src="http://theparlour21.se/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/granat-salad.png"></a>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
  </div>

</div>



<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>

</body>
```

Comment: It's not a good idea to have multiple elements with the same image. Use class for that

Comment: Consider using multiple same classes on a page not multiple ids.

Comment: Do you want achieve this in javascript or jQuery?

Comment: There is problem with id having same name. Use multiple class with same name instead of id. Definitely it will solve your problem.

Comment: @vel : By jquery

Comment: you can use multiple class with same name instead of id?

Comment: @vel: I tried to replace the id with class but didn't work

Comment: check this https://jsfiddle.net/gnanavelr/w6cb0unn/1/ do you want like this?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gnanavelr/w6cb0unn/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a href="#" id="myBtn" class="popupmodel"><img src="http://theparlour21.se/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/granat-salad.png"></a>
<a href="#" id="myBtn" class="popupmodel"><img src="http://theparlour21.se/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/granat-salad.png"></a>
<a href="#" id="myBtn" class="popupmodel"><img src="http://theparlour21.se/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/granat-salad.png"></a>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
  </div>

</div>




$(document).ready(function(){

    $(document).on("click",".close,.modal", function(){
            $(".modal").hide();
    });

    $(document).on("click",".popupmodel", function(){
            $(".modal").show();
    });
});
```

[fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/gnanavelr/w6cb0unn/2/)

Comment: Glad to help you

Answer (score 0):

Working code. Try this.

```
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>

    /* The Modal (background) */
    .modal {
        display: none; /* Hidden by default */
        position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
        z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
        padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%; /* Full width */
        height: 100%; /* Full height */
        overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
        background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
    }

    /* Modal Content */
    .modal-content {
        background-color: #fefefe;
        margin: auto;
        padding: 20px;
        border: 1px solid #888;
        width: 80%;
    }

    /* The Close Button */
    .close {
        color: #aaaaaa;
        float: right;
        font-size: 28px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    .close:hover,
    .close:focus {
        color: #000;
        text-decoration: none;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<a href="#" id="myBtn" class="myBtn"><img src="http://theparlour21.se/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/granat-salad.png"></a>
<a href="#" id="myBtn" class="myBtn"><img src="http://theparlour21.se/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/granat-salad.png"></a>
<a href="#" id="myBtn" class="myBtn"><img src="http://theparlour21.se/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/granat-salad.png"></a>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
// btn.onclick = function() {
//     modal.style.display = "block";
// }
$(".myBtn").click(function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";   
});

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>
</body>
```